# TF OD API checkpointing and evaluation

Tags: tensorflow, metrics, object-detection-api

It seems that regardless of passing the default checkpoint in the `pipeline.config` file **OR** a saved checkpoint after fine-tuning, I always get metrics equal to zero on the first round of evaluation (see below). Is this intended behavior? It leads me to believe fine-tuning didn't do anything. I'm doing training and eval with the official tf code from  https://github.com/tensorflow/models :

`/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py`

Test 1: uses tf official checkpoint for frozen model (ssd_mobilenet_v2)

`fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"`

```
I1216 22:26:26.234447 139743384397632 model_lib_v2.py:1007] Eval metrics at step 0
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.000000
I1216 22:26:26.239099 139743384397632 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.000000
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.000000
I1216 22:26:26.240221 139743384397632 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.000000
```

Test 2: uses saved checkpoint after I did fine-tuning

`fine_tune_checkpoint: "my_new_model/ckpt-71"`

```
Eval metrics at step 0
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.000000
I1216 22:49:32.352353 139835185157952 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.000000
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.000000
I1216 22:49:32.353258 139835185157952 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.000000
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU: 0.000000
I1216 22:49:32.353990 139835185157952 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU: 0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[Tensorflow Object Detection API: Train from exported model checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673499/tensorflow-object-detection-api-train-from-exported-model-checkpoint?rq=1)

By setting fine_tune_checkpoint_type to "full", I got the correct mAP for the first checkpoint (at 0 steps).